# Third tier in drop down menu not working in IE7 only

Tags: css, html

I'm having some difficulty with a CSS only menu in Ie7. So far the code works fine in Ie8+ and it works fine in Ie9 when I use the developer toolbar and set it to Ie7. However when I test a real version of Ie7 or use IEtester, the initial drop down works however the 3rd tier (flyout from drop down) does not and its driving me nutty. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
/* Drop Down */

/* 1st Tier */
header nav ul li {float: left; position: relative;}
/* 2nd Tier */
header nav ul ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px;}
header nav ul li:hover ul {top:59px; left:0px;}
/* 3rd Tier */
header nav ul li:hover ul ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px;}
header nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {top:0; left:215px;}
/* 4th Tier */
header nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px;}
header nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {top:0; left:215px;}
/* Dropdown Link Styles */
header nav li:hover ul a {min-width: 200px; padding:10px 8px; background: #3a3a3a; color: #797979; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #777;}
header nav li:hover ul a:hover {background:#3a3a3a; color: #eee;}
header nav li:hover ul li:hover a {background: #282828;}
header nav li:hover ul li li a:hover {background: #1f1f1f;}
header nav li:hover ul li:hover li:hover a {background: #1f1f1f;}
header nav li:hover ul li:hover li a:hover {background: #1f1f1f;}
header nav li:hover ul li:hover li li:hover a:hover {background: #000;}
```

HTML:

```
<header>

                <nav>

                    <a class="logo" href="#hidden" title=""></a>

                    <ul>

                        <li class="firstli"><a class="home" href="#hidden" title=""></a></li>

                        <li class="page_item page-item-830"><a class="plans" href="#hiddenplan" title="Plans"><span>Plans</span></a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-14328 firstli"><a href="#hiddenplan/institutional-strategic-development" title="Institutional Strategic Development">Institutional Strategic Development</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-14643 firstli lastli"><a href="#hiddenplan/institutional-strategic-development/strategic-plan-fy13-fy15" title="Strategic Plan FY13 &ndash; FY15">Strategic Plan FY13 &ndash; FY15</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-826"><a href="#hiddenplans-companion-animals" title="Companion Animal Strategy">Companion Animal Strategy</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-14719 firstli"><a href="#hiddenplan/companion-animal-strategy/companion-animals-advisory-planning" title="Companion Animals Advisory Planning">Companion Animals Advisory Planning</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-15261 lastli"><a href="#hiddenplan/companion-animal-strategy/companion-animals-advisory-planning-documents" title="Companion Animals Advisory Planning Documents">Companion Animals Advisory Planning Documents</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-505"><a href="#hiddenplans-elephant-program" title="Elephant Program Strategy">Elephant Program Strategy</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-478"><a href="#hiddenplans-animal-rescue" title="Animal Rescue Strategy">Animal Rescue Strategy</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-827"><a href="#hiddenplans-seal-program" title="Seal program Strategy">Seal program Strategy</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-715"><a href="#hiddenplans-whale-program" title="Whale Program Strategy">Whale Program Strategy</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-828"><a href="#hiddenplans-wildlife-crime-and-consumption" title="Wildlife Crime and Consumption Strategy">Wildlife Crime and Consumption Strategy</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-829 lastli"><a href="#hiddenplans-other-campaigns-projects" title="Other Campaigns &amp; Projects">Other Campaigns &amp; Projects</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-831"><a class="messages" href="#hiddenmessage" title="Key Messages"><span>Key Messages</span></a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-3909 firstli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/position-statements" title="Position Statements">Position Statements</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2035"><a href="#hiddenmessage/companion-animal-messages" title="Companion Animal Messages">Companion Animal Messages</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-2037 firstli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/companion-animal-messages/guidelines-warning-notes" title="Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes">Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2038"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ifaw.org/ifaw_international/publications/program_publications/help_dogs_and_cats.php" title="Publications">Publications</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-8877"><a href="#hiddenother-useful-ifaw-information-companion-animals" title="Other useful IFAW information">Other useful IFAW information</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9040"><a href="#hiddeninformation-from-other-sources-companion-animals" title="Information from other sources">Information from other sources</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-3030 lastli"><a href="#hiddenwish-lists-proposals-companion-animals" title="Wish Lists &amp; Proposals">Wish Lists &amp; Proposals</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-4140"><a href="#hiddenmessage/elephant-program-messages-2" title="Elephant Program Messages">Elephant Program Messages</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-1516 firstli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/elephant-program-messages-2/guidelines-warning-notes" title="Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes">Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1013"><a href="#hiddenmessage/elephant-program-messages-2/elephant-program" title="Publications">Publications</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9157"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddenother-useful-ifaw-information-elephants" title="Other useful IFAW information">Other useful IFAW information</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9159"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddeninformation-from-other-sources-elephants" title="Information from other sources">Information from other sources</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5557 lastli"><a href="#hiddenwish-lists-proposals-elephants" title="Wish Lists &amp; Proposals">Wish Lists &amp; Proposals</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-1202"><a href="#hiddenmessage/emergency-relief-program-key-messages" title="Animal Rescue Messages">Animal Rescue Messages</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-5704 firstli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/emergency-relief-program-key-messages/guidelines-warning-notes" title="Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes">Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1203"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ifaw.org/ifaw_united_states/publications/program_publications/provide_emergency_relief.php" title="Publications">Publications</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9162"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddenother-useful-ifaw-information-emergency-relief" title="Other useful IFAW information">Other useful IFAW information</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9163"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddeninformation-from-other-sources-emergency-relief" title="Information from other sources">Information from other sources</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5705"><a href="#hiddenmessage/emergency-relief-program-key-messages/er-response-list" title="ER Response List">ER Response List</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5558 lastli"><a href="#hiddenwish-lists-proposals-emergency-relief" title="Wish Lists &amp; Proposals">Wish Lists &amp; Proposals</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-1087"><a href="#hiddenmessage/seal-program-messages" title="Seal Program Message">Seal Program Message</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-2034 firstli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/seal-program-messages/guidelines-warning-notes" title="Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes">Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1088"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ifaw.org/ifaw_international/publications/program_publications/save_baby_seals.php" title="Publications">Publications</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9164"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddenother-useful-ifaw-information-seals" title="Other useful IFAW information">Other useful IFAW information</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9165"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddeninformation-from-other-sources-seals" title="Information from other sources">Information from other sources</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5559 lastli"><a href="#hiddenwish-lists-proposals-&ndash;-seals" title="Wish Lists &amp; Proposals">Wish Lists &amp; Proposals</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2039"><a href="#hiddenmessage/whale-program-messages" title="Whale Program Messages">Whale Program Messages</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-2040 firstli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/whale-program-messages/guidelines-warning-notes" title="Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes">Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2041"><a href="http://www.mywhaleweb.com/?page_id=1064&amp;media=documents&amp;id=search" title="Publications">Publications</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-2211 firstli lastli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/whale-program-messages/supporting-facts-publications/lucky-the-north-atlantic-right-whale" title="Lucky the North Atlantic Right Whale">Lucky the North Atlantic Right Whale</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9085"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddenother-useful-ifaw-information-whales" title="Other useful IFAW information">Other useful IFAW information</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9086"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddeninformation-from-other-sources-whales" title="Information from other sources">Information from other sources</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5560"><a href="#hiddenwish-lists-proposals-&ndash;whales" title="Wish Lists &amp; Proposals">Wish Lists &amp; Proposals</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-6395 lastli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/whale-program-messages/northern-right-whaleship-strike-rule-talking-points-and-key-messaging" title="Northern Right Whale/Ship Strike Rule Talking Points and Key Messaging">Northern Right Whale/Ship Strike Rule Talking Points and Key Messaging</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2042"><a href="#hiddenmessage/wildlife-trade-program-messages" title="Wildlife Crime and Consumption Messages">Wildlife Crime and Consumption Messages</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-2043 firstli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/wildlife-trade-program-messages/guidelines-warning-notes" title="Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes">Guidelines &amp; Warning Notes</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2044"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ifaw.org/ifaw_united_states/publications/program_publications/fight_illegal_trade_in_wildlife/index.php" title="Publications">Publications</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9166"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddenother-useful-ifaw-information-wildlife-trade" title="Other useful IFAW information">Other useful IFAW information</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9167"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddeninformation-from-other-sources-wildlife-trade" title="Information from other sources">Information from other sources</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5556 lastli"><a href="#hiddenwish-lists-proposals-&ndash;-wildlife-trade" title="Wish Lists &amp; Proposals">Wish Lists &amp; Proposals</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2381"><a href="#hiddenmessage/no-return-to-cruelty-campaign-messages" title="“No Return To Cruelty” &ndash; Hunting with Dogs, UK">“No Return To Cruelty” &ndash; Hunting with Dogs, UK</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-2383 firstli lastli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/no-return-to-cruelty-campaign-messages/supporting-facts-publications-2" title="Publications and facts">Publications and facts</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-5081 lastli"><a href="#hiddenmessage/tiger-key-messages-2" title="Tiger Campaign">Tiger Campaign</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-833"><a class="comms" href="#hiddencomms" title="Comms"><span>Comms</span></a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-15873 firstli"><a href="#hiddencomms/2011-branding-and-marketing-report" title="2011 Branding and Marketing Report">2011 Branding and Marketing Report</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-14909"><a href="#hiddencomms/comms-strategies-and-plans" title="Comms Strategies and Plans">Comms Strategies and Plans</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8225"><a href="#hiddencomms/communications-standards" title="Communications Standards">Communications Standards</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-12416"><a href="#hiddencomms/institutional-publications" title="Institutional Publications">Institutional Publications</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-13062 firstli lastli"><a href="#hiddencomms/institutional-publications/2011-animal-action-elephants-education-materials" title="2011 Animal Action Elephants Education Materials">2011 Animal Action Elephants Education Materials</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-1629"><a href="#hiddencomms/media-reports" title="Media Reports">Media Reports</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-9678"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010" title="Global Comms Meeting 2010">Global Comms Meeting 2010</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-9870 firstli"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/branding-guidelines-policies" title="Branding Guidelines / Policies">Branding Guidelines / Policies</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9772"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/great-comms-examples" title="Great Comm’s examples">Great Comm’s examples</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9759"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/er-statergy" title="ER Strategy">ER Strategy</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9760"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/companion-animals" title="Companion Animals">Companion Animals</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9871"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/international-convention-and-agreeement" title="International Convention and Agreeement">International Convention and Agreeement</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9761"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/elephants" title="Elephants">Elephants</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9762"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/wildlife-trade" title="Wildlife Trade">Wildlife Trade</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9774"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/ivory-campaign" title="Ivory Campaign">Ivory Campaign</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9763"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/seals" title="Seals">Seals</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9764"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/whales" title="Whales">Whales</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9742"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/ocm-presentation" title="OCM Presentation">OCM Presentation</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-10042 lastli"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-comms-meeting-2010/web-redesign" title="Web Redesign">Web Redesign</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-1640"><a href="#hiddencomms/global-communications-calendar" title="Global Communications Calendar">Global Communications Calendar</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-9991 lastli"><a href="#hiddencomms/website-redesign" title="Website Redesign">Website Redesign</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-834"><a class="reports" href="#hiddenreport" title="Reports"><span>Reports</span></a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-19785 firstli"><a href="#hiddenanimal-rescue/report" title="Animal Rescue">Animal Rescue</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-19787 lastli"><a href="http://#hiddenanimal-rescue/report" title="animal rescue 2">animal rescue 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2080 lastli"><a class="help" href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials" title="Help &amp; Tutorials"><span>Help &amp; Tutorials</span></a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-4798 firstli"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/administrative-policies-and-procedures" title="Administrative Policies and Procedures">Administrative Policies and Procedures</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2373"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/quick-video-tutorials" title="How to find what you need">How to find what you need</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2148"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/how-to-submit-info-by-email" title="How to submit info by email">How to submit info by email</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-7250 firstli"><a target="_blank" href="#hiddenwp-content/uploads/2011/07/Instructions-for-adding-pre-built-Program-Info-signatures-to-Outlook.pdf" title="How to add pre-built “Program Info” signatures into Outlook">How to add pre-built “Program Info” signatures into Outlook</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-17603 lastli"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/how-to-submit-info-by-email/how-to-self-publish-posts-submitted-by-email" title="How to self-publish posts submitted by email">How to self-publish posts submitted by email</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2572"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/how-to-set-up-personalized-news-feeds" title="How to set up personalized news feeds">How to set up personalized news feeds</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-14586"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-post-and-large-attachments-through-the-dashboard" title="How to add a post and large attachments through the dashboard">How to add a post and large attachments through the dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2143"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/request-support-or-make-a-suggestion" title="Request help or make suggestion">Request help or make suggestion</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-3257 lastli"><a href="#hiddenhelp-tutorials/protocols" title="Protocols">Protocols</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. It was something lame of course. IE7 just wanted some padding.

```
header nav ul :hover ul :hover ul,
header nav ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul,
header nav ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul {padding:0 1px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems come to mind:

- You might not be using `strict` doc-type.  [IE7 won't register hover events on non-anchors in `quirks` mode](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762).
- You are declaring `strict`, but you are getting bumped to `quirks` because IE7 doesn't understand `<header>` and `<nav>` - but [you can fix that with a bit of JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862337/286599).

Comment: This is not the issue at hand. While I am using an html5 doctype and I am also using the html5 shiv. I have not had this issue before and it's probably something stupid like applying a width or line-height for IE7 but so far I haven't figured it because it's been awhile since I've done Ie7 specific development but I have gotten the drop downs to work in the past.

Comment: Ok.  Alas, I cannot help more - I only have IE8 and IE6 VM's set up...  Good luck.

Comment: You should download IETester if those are all you have.http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: IETester isn't quite reliable enough for my purposes, especially with how it handles AJAX DOM updates, but thanks for the thought.  (I'd just set up another VM for IE7 if I needed it.)  Glad you figured out the problem!