# CSS selectors not applying in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

Having a weird issue with IE that I've never seen before.

A whole bunch of my selectors just aren't applying at all in IE7 and IE8. They work fine in IE9 and good browsers.

To see the effect in action, just focus on the logo in the top left of this site: [www.rtotv.com.au](http://www.rtotv.com.au). Using developer tools (F12) in IE9, find this element:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="row header clearfix">
      <h1 class="span3 logo">
        <a title="RTO TV Home" class="ir" href="/">   <--this element
```

The styles.css stylesheet is loading fine, and the .ir class is applying, but as an example, this style selector doesn't apply AT ALL in IE7 & 8, but works perfectly in IE9:

```
header h1.logo a {}
```

If I can figure out what is happening here, I'm sure I'll be able to fix the rest of the site, but right now, this is completely destroying the site in IE7 & 8.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859716/how-can-i-use-html5-in-all-browsers-including-ie7-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site is built using HTML5 which not supported by ie7 and ie8 and not fully supported by ie9.

take a look for modernizr :

> Modernizr is an open-source JavaScript library that helps you build the next generation of HTML5 and CSS3-powered websites.

or you may want to re-factor your HTML using XHTML by replacing `nav`, `section`, `header` tag with supported tags

Answer (score 2):

This is because of IE not suporting HTML5. Add following script to render html5 in IE. And add a class to header element then style using that class.

```
document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("footer");
document.createElement("header");
document.createElement("hgroup");
document.createElement("nav");
```

Comment: Don't forget to add CSS for each of those elements to "reset" the HTML5 element created with the above script to display block (the default is inline).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to "fill the gaps".