# Does IE7 support HTML5 data tag?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm willing to use data tag as below.

```
<div data-color="#1337c"></div>
```

I use jquery to **fetch**(`$("div").data("color");`) and **store**`($("div").data("color", "red");`) as well as manipulate data.

- Will IE7 support above tag ?
- What is the browser requirement for HTML5 ?

Thanks

Comment: you can refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859716/how-can-i-use-html5-in-all-browsers-including-ie7-8)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer the *real question*: **`jQuery.data` works as expected in IE7 .. and IE6.** (No HTML5 or official "data attribute" support required.)

IE7 will happily keep *any* attribute supplied in the HTML and expose it as such in the DOM. It doesn't matter if it is called `data-foo` or `foo-data`. I believe this is technically against the HTML4 specification, but it is the behavior of *every* major browser I know.

Do be aware, however, that `data("foo")` and `attr("data-foo")` have different semantics.

Comment: If you can please tell me what's the difference between jQuery.data and jQuery.attr("data-foo") ?

Comment: @Dasun Lots of good questions already on this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+data+vs+data+attribute (although I might have it wrong in my memory, I believe that `data` doesn't need to write-though to the data-attributes; that is, it does not necessarily modify the DOM and can work with non-stringifiable objects)

Comment: which one do you prefer in this scenario ? what do you recommend for me to use ?

Comment: @Dasun Honestly, I have only used `data`, and *only* for reading "data attributes"; I have never used it for storing new data, however, as I prefer closures and other techniques of data management.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, data attributes are not actually HTML5 features, but rather their use became standardized in HTML5. IE 5.5 (from what I remember) was actually the first browser to support pseudo attributes, but don't quote me on that :v