# Ajax content sortable jQuery portlets, order by 'sortOrder' variable after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a conumdrum and am looking for advice as to the best way to proceed. I have a tabbed portlet interface set up. Tabs are generated dynamically from a JSON response, and then portlets for each tab are loaded from another web service JSON response on first tab activation. The portlets need to be ordered by a pre-determined variable returned from the JSON (currently they are loaded in the order the ajax requests return).

I am looking for the simplest way to do this. My initial thinking is to append the variable to a class on portlet creation to end up with HTML mark-up similar to:

```
<div class="tabBody">
   <div class="portlet sortOrder1">Content</div>
   <div class="portlet sortOrder4">Content</div>
   <div class="portlet sortOrder2">Content</div>
   <div class="portlet sortOrder5">Content</div>
   <div class="portlet sortOrder3">Content</div>
</div>
```

And then sort them after all portlets have been loaded using javascript with something similar to:

```
tab.find('sortOrder2').insertAfter(tab.find('.sortOrder1'));
```

As a quick example (with tab being a variable). The actual implementation would be a bit more complex, as I'll likely loop through all portlets, wildcard the sortOrder selector and parse out the int as the number of portlets per tab is not static.

Am I missing something and there's a painfully simple way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE:*

I have implemented the answer given below by @André Snede Hansen and it's working perfectly. Sort Order is achieved through the data attribute method (rather than using classes as I was originally intending) dynamically adding the integers returned from each response and then sorting at the end of my portletify (adding ui classes sortable etc) tab method.

Testing in IE back to 7 with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a quick way to solve what you are looking for**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tabBody">
    <div class="portlet" data-order="1">Content1</div>
    <div class="portlet" data-order="4">Content4</div>
    <div class="portlet" data-order="2">Content2</div>
    <div class="portlet" data-order="5">Content5</div>
    <div class="portlet" data-order="3">Content3</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".tabBody .portlet").sort(function(x, y){
   var orderX = parseInt($(x).attr("data-order"),10) || 0;
   var orderY = parseInt($(y).attr("data-order"),10) || 0;
   return orderX - orderY;
}).appendTo($(".tabBody"));
```

**[I have made a JSFiddle for the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/bKTz4/)**

`$(".tabBody .portlet")` returns an array of elemets, and arrays have a **`sort`** method.
The sort method is described further here: **[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

Comment: I hadn't thought of html-5 data-* attributes, how compatible are these cross browser? Thinking specifically of ie 7+ which will be a requirement here.

Comment: AFAIK, this will work in any browser, even IE7, though it might not validate. If you find that it doesn't, you could also use the class you provided, and analyze the string, convert it to a number, and then compare it.

Comment: IE support for `data-` attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576592/does-ie7-support-html5-data-tag

Comment: Perfect thank you. Shouldn't have any issues with the data-attributes then (considering that even if they're not recognized they're kept regardless), but will report back if I do for future reference.

Comment: Implemented and tested back to IE 7 with no issues. Thanks again.